# Collisions in Visual Python

Tags: python

I'm currently doing a school project that wants 2D pong made in Visual Python. Right now, I've set my current collisions of the 2 paddles at the bottom of the code. When it runs, it decides to go through it and hit the green walls (Which I will change to clear walls later). Even with the paddle no where near the ball, it still detects a "wall" present and bounces off, which I'm pretty sure its creating a massive skinny wall on the x axis where the paddle is, but is stretched vertically. I do not know any other way my teacher taught other than this way. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from visual import *

# Title Screen
def TitleScreen():
    
    # Display
    sceneTest = display(title='Pong', x=0, y=0, width=950,
                        height=950, center=(5,0,0), background=(1,1,1))
    #autoscale
    sceneTest.autoscale = False
    
     #Back Wall
    wallBack = box(pos = vector(2,0,-2), size=(50,50,0.2), color = color.black)

     #Ball
    ballPong = box(pos = vector(5,1,0), size=(0.5,0.5,0.01), color = color.white)

     #Left Stick
    stick1 = box(pos = vector(-6,0,0), size=(0.5, 5, 0.2), color = color.white)

     #Right Stick
    stick2 = box(pos = vector(16,0,0), size=(0.5, 5, 0.2), color = color.white)


    # Title Text
    titleScreenText = text(text = "Pong", pos = (5,9, 0), align = "center",
                           depth = 0.01, height = 1.5, width = 1.5,
                           color = color.white)
    # Start Game
    titleScreenText = text(text = "Press E to Start", pos = (-1.5,-8.5, 0),
                           depth = 0.01, height = 1.5, width = 1.5,
                           color = color.white)

    # Main Loop for starting game
    while True:
        rate(30)
        if sceneTest.kb.keys:
            key = sceneTest.kb.getkey()
            if key == "e":
                sceneTest.delete()
                pongGame() 


# Main Game Loop
def pongGame():

    # Game Display
    newDisplay = display(title='Pong', x=0, y=0,width=950,
                        height=950, center=(5,0,0), background=(1,1,1))

    
    newDisplay.autoscale = False
    
    # BlackWall
    wallBack = box(pos = vector(2.5,0,-2), size=(50,50,0.2), color = color.black)

    ball2 = box(pos = vector(5,0,0), size=(0.5,0.5,0.5), color = color.white)
    
    # Stick Paddle 1
    stick1New = box(pos = vector(-6,0,0), size=(0.5, 5, 0.2), color = color.white)

    # Stick Paddle 2
    stick2New = box(pos = vector(16,0,0), size=(0.5, 5, 0.2), color = color.white)


    #Clear Wall Left Boundary                                color = color.green) opacity= 0.01
    wallClear1 = box(pos=vector(-6.5,0,0), size=(0.2,22,0.3), color = color.green)

    #Clear Wall Right Boundary
    wallClear2 = box(pos=vector(16.5,0,0), size=(0.2,22,0.3), color = color.green)

    # Clear Wall Top Boundary
    wallClear3 = box(pos=vector(5,11,0), size=(23,0.2,0.3), color = color.green)

    # Clear Bottom Boudary
    wallClear4 = box(pos=vector(5,-11,0), size=(23,0.2,0.3), color = color.green)
    
   
    # Ball Velocity Initial
    ball2.velocity = vector(11,0)
    deltaT = 0.005
    t = 0.0

    # Scoreboard
    player1Score = 0
    player2Score = 0
    scoreText = ("{} :   {}".format(player1Score, player2Score))
    scoreTextDisplay = text(text = scoreText, pos = (5,9, 0), align = "center", depth = 0.1, height = 1.5, width = 1.5, color = color.white)

    while True:
        # Refresh
        rate(100)
        # Ball Velocity while Running
        t = t + deltaT
        ball2.pos = ball2.pos + ball2.velocity*deltaT

##
##        # Literal Aimbot
##        stick2New.velocity = vector(0,3)
##        stick2New.pos = stick2New.pos + stick2New.velocity*deltaT
##        stick2New.pos.y = ball2.pos.y
##

        # Player 1 Input/Controls
        if newDisplay.kb.keys:
            keyNew = newDisplay.kb.getkey()
            
            # Moving Up 
            if keyNew == "w":
                stick1New.pos.y = stick1New.pos.y + 0.25

            # Moving Down
            if keyNew == "s":
                stick1New.pos.y = stick1New.pos.y - 0.25


        # If ball hits Right wall
        if ball2.pos.x > wallClear2.pos.x:
            ball2.velocity.x = ball2.velocity.x
            player1Score = player1Score + 1
            ball2.pos = (5,0,0)
            
        # If ball hits Left wall
        if ball2.pos.x < wallClear1.pos.x:
            ball2.velocity.x = ball2.velocity.x
            player2Score = player2Score + 1
            ball2.pos = (5,0,0)

        # If the Ball hits the top of the Wall
        if ball2.pos.y > wallClear3.pos.y:
            ball2.velocity.y = -ball2.velocity.y

        # If the Ball hits the bottom of the Wall
        if ball2.pos.y < wallClear4.pos.y:
            ball2.velocity.y = -ball2.velocity.y


        # Collisions Check OLD
        # if ball hits right paddle
##        if ball2.pos.x < stick2New.pos.x: #or ball2.pos.x > stick2New.pos.x:
##            ball2.velocity.x = -ball2.velocity.x
##        if ball2.pos.x > (stick2New.pos.x == -6) or ball2.pos.x < (stick2New.pos.x > -6):
##            ball2.velocity.x = -ball2.velocity.x
            
            
        # if ball hits left paddle
        if ball2.pos.x < stick1New.pos.x:
            ball2.velocity.x = -ball2.velocity.x

        if ball2.pos.x > stick2New.pos.x:
            ball2.velocity.x = -ball2.velocity.x


TitleScreen()
```

Comment: Can you update your code to run with the latest version of vpython? You will need to make a few small changes. I can no longer download your version of visual python from pypi.org. Also, I don't think you are checking the y coordinate of your ball when checking collisions against the paddles. This will make the paddles appear infinitely tall.

Comment: What library are you using exactly? Please add the tag if it exists. I looked up [Visual Python](https://github.com/visualpython/visualpython#readme) but it seems to be something different. Are you actually using [VPython](https://vpython.org/)? I'm not familiar with either of them myself. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @wjandrea From what I can tell, OP is using some older distribution of visual python, before it was ported to VPython. Unfortunately, VPython made a bunch of small syntax changes so some code adaptations are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have any code to check the y coordinate of the ball when checking collisions with the paddles. This will make the paddles appear infinitely tall. You can incorporate some code like `if (ball2.pos.x < stick1New.pos.x) and abs(ball2.pos.y-stick1New.pos.y) < 2.5: ball2.velocity.x*=-1; ball2.velocity.y *=-1;`